# Inherited method has no access to new implementation in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, method-hiding

As referenced in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx):

The type object of derived class has no access to the new re-defined method inherited from base class and the call on an object of derived class from `ShowDetails()` Method inside the inherited Method `DescribeCar()` is made to the `ShowDetails()` Method of base class.

if the `DescribeCar()` Method is also available to the `ConvertibleCar` class, How come it cannot see the so-called `new ShowDetails()` Method?

```
class Car
{
    public void DescribeCar()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Four wheels and an engine.");
        ShowDetails();
    }

    public virtual void ShowDetails()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Standard transportation.");
    }
}

// Define the derived classes.

// Class ConvertibleCar uses the new modifier to acknowledge that ShowDetails
// hides the base class method.
class ConvertibleCar : Car
{
    public new void ShowDetails()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("A roof that opens up.");
    }
}


class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConvertibleCar car2 = new ConvertibleCar();
        car2.DescribeCar();
    }
}

//output
// Four wheels and an engine.
// Standard transportation.
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. `Car.DescribeCar` only "knows about" `Car.ShowDetails`... which could be *overridden* in `ConvertibleCar`, but that's not what the code does. Instead, it declares a new method...

Comment: Because you said it was `new`, i.e. it doesn't `override` but hides the other implementation.

Comment: The difference between new and override is that methods defined as new will not be called when the object is being treated as the superclass, which overrides will.

Comment: What I'm asking refers is about ConvertibleCar.DescribeCar()

Comment: DescribeCar is defined in Car and can't "see" your "new" method.  Frankly you almost never want to use the new keyword on methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new` **hides** the old method, which means that if you *directly* call it on a `ConvertibleCar` instance, you will get the derived class behavior, but it won't be called *polymorphically*.

When the base class calls it, it is calling the virtual method, which since it hasn't been overridden invokes the base class method. Instead of using method hiding (which you almost *never* use anyways), just override it:

```
class ConvertibleCar : Car
{
    public override void ShowDetails()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("A roof that opens up.");
    }
}
```

Comment: "which means that if you directly call it on a ConvertibleCar instance, you will get the derived class behavior" -- Can you elaborate on this?  It looks like he/she *is* calling it directly on a ConvertibleCar instance via `car2.DescribeCar();`

Comment: @roryap I'll certainly try. The trick is that he *isn't* directly calling it on a `ConvertibleCar` instance, he's calling an inherited base class method that invokes a virtual method (and so doesn't know about the hiding method in the derived class)

Comment: Ahh, i just saw where my confusion was stemming from.  I was mixing up `DescribeCar` and `ShowDetails`.  For some reason I thought he was calling `car2.ShowDetails()` which would obviously call the derived class method.

Comment: @ BradleyDotNET "When the base class calls it, it is calling the virtual method", why is that expected? I'm calling it from DescribeCar which is available to ConvertibleCar class, but it cannot see the new method?

Comment: @user3723486 Because ConvertibleCar does not define its own DescribeCar method.

Comment: @user3723486 Thats expected because it can only see other methods in the base class (for example, the virtual method you defined). If you defined some random *other* method in the derived class, the base class wouldn't see *it* either. By hiding the base class method you break the polymorphic behavior you were expecting. Using `override` allows the call to "redirect" to the derived version.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I think my confusion is with inheritance, when `DescribeCar` Method is inherited, is that not copied to the derived class as if you have defined it in the class?

Comment: @user3723486 No, not really. It certainly *acts* that way from client code, but it still is very much a member of the base class.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. but need more elaboration on inheritance in details

Comment: @user3723486 Please join me in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73802/inheritance-discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-user3723486 to discuss this further

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you think about it - think of **no** inheritance - this is like asking why does `Car.DescribeCar` not have access to `ConvertibleCar.ShowDetails`.

`ConvertibleCar.ShowDetails` is essentially a method that isn't a member of `Car` if you like - because of the `new` keyword. `Car` however has a method `ShowDetails`.

`Car.DescribeCar` as a member method of `Car`, has visibility of `Car.ShowDetails` and not `ConvertibleCar.ShowDetails`, thus `Car.ShowDetails` is what gets invoked.

Maybe this would be clearer. With the `new` keyword, this is another way to think about it:

```
class Car
{
  ...
  public virtual void ShowDetails(){..}
}

class ConvertibleCar : Car
{
  public void new_ShowDetails(){}
}
```

`Car` has no knowledge of `ConvertibleCar.new_ShowDetails` so can't invoke the method.

Comment: You could even still derive and your example would be accurate :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are true, but I want to show an example of what happens inside the `DescribeCar()` method.

```
public void DescribeCar()
{
    Type t = this.GetType();
    //bad hack
    dynamic _this = Convert.ChangeType(this, t);

    this.ShowDetails(); //Prints "Standard transportation."
    _this.ShowDetails(); //Prints "A roof that opens up."
}
```

`t` is `ConvertibleCar` because it is the actual type of the object, but the `this` variable (that is actually a parameter of every non-static method hidden by the compiler) is of type `Car`.

The specific thing about `virtual` methods is that when they are called by your code, the compiler does an additional lookup at the actual type of the object (i.e. calls `GetType()`) and checks if any type in your hierarchy has overridden the method. Then it calls the newest implementation of your method.
But if you use `new` instead of `override`, this lookup yields no results and the base implementation is used. If you use `new` the only way to call the new implementation is to cast your variable to the type the new implementation was defined in.

Comment: How to confirm the type of `this` keyword?

Comment: @user3723486 The `GetType()` method returns the actual type of the object, not the type of the reference. The type of the `this` reference will be the same as the class your method is defined in.